# Installed Oculus Go Mobile SDK, VrSamples missing

Tags: oculus, oculusgo

I installed the Oculus Go Mobile SDK, and wanted to use the sample projects in VrSamples to start understanding development. However, the one that seems to be most relevant for a beginner, and is quoted in all tutorials/documentation I see, is not included. Namely after installing the Oculus Go Mobile SDK from https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-mobile-sdk/, in VrSamples I only see the following projects:

```
CinemaSDK/           
VrCompositor_NativeActivity/
Oculus360VideosSDK/
Oculus360PhotosSDK/
VrController/      
VrCubeWorld_NativeActivity/
VrCubeWorld_SurfaceView/
VrCubeWorld_Vulkan/
VrTemplate/
```

The one that is quoted in tutorials, and seems to be the best for a beginner to start with, should be called `VrCubeworld_Framework` (for instance it is used as an example here https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-studio-basics/ ). However, this one is missing. Why is that? Is it deprecated?